# Robolectric.getSentHttpRequest(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to test retrofit with robolectric. But I always get an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I call Robolectric.getSentHttpRequest(0). Can anyone help me?

here is my code:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Robolectric.setDefaultHttpResponse(200, "OK");
    commonRequest = RequestFactory.getRestAdapter().create(CommonRequest.class);
}

@Test
public void testGet_shouldApplyCorrectHeaders() throws Exception {
    commonRequest.register("Token", "{}", null);
    HttpRequest sentHttpRequest = Robolectric.getSentHttpRequest(0);
    assertThat(sentHttpRequest.getHeaders("Authorization")[0].getValue(), equalTo("Token"));
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're missing the send request part. That's why you keep getting IndexOutOfBoundsException. You should send the request first take a look in the first example (testGet_FormsCorrectRequest_noBasicAuth) [here](https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/pivotallabs/api/HttpTest.java)